# MBSync Maildir++ to IMAP with subfolder in INBOX

Tags: synchronization, mailx, imap

I am trying to use MBSync to sync a local Maildir++ folder (dovecot mail data) into a remote IMAP mailbox. While it works in general, subdirs of INBOX are ignored.

Config looks like this:

```
MaildirStore a-local
Subfolders Maildir++
Inbox /var/kunden/mail/a/foo@bar.com
IMAPAccount a
Host ***
User ***
Pass ***
SSLType IMAPS
CertificateFile ~/mail/cert

IMAPStore a-remote
Account a

Channel a
Master :a-local:
Slave :a-remote:
Patterns *
SyncState ~/mail/a-imap-transfer
```

Ouput looks like this (why is INBOX ignored?!)

```
pattern '*' (effective '*'): Path, no INBOX Maildir warning: ignoring
INBOX in /var/kunden/mail/a/foo@bar.com/ Opening slave
store a-remote... Resolving ***... ok Connecting to
*** (***:993)... Connection is now encrypted Logging in... Authenticating with SASL mechanism PLAIN... pattern '*'
(effective '*'): Path, no INBOX Opening master box INBOX... Opening
slave box INBOX...
```

The folder structure in file system looks like this:

```
 .Drafts
'.Entw&APw-rfe'
 .Gesendet
 .INBOX.abizeitung
 .INBOX.Bachelorarbeit
 .INBOX.bestellungen
 .INBOX.dav
```

the last 4 of those are NOT synced.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage: `Note that INBOX is not matched by wildcards, unless it lives under Path.`. So you would have to add a second pattern `.INBOX.*`.